# Ecu is wakeup and starts transmitting. But some signals are not updating to desired value

Tags: autosar

I have a scenario where ECU is wake up and started transmitting. But some of the signals are not updating to desired value. Can someone tell me what could be the issue or how can be resolved

Answer (score 0):

The info about *signals are not updated to desired value* is a bit vague, do you see actually a new frame being transmitted? How dou you check this? e.g. tools visualizing signal values keep the last seen value, but do you actually see new frames (containing the signals) at all?

Maybe the frame is not even newly transmitted due to Tx-IPduGroups not enabled, or the IPduTriggering conditions are not fulfilled, e.g. the signals are just transmitted on event like DataChanged.

The ISignalIpdu is has IPduTiming only on Event, but your ISignals have property "PENDING" set.

Maybe the SWCs updating the signals over its ports with e.g. `Rte_Write` are not in a state where their runnables are actually run?

Maybe the  SWCs ports with the data elements are not properly mapped the System/I-Signals.

Maybe the signals are updated, but the transformation is wrong or even you SWC has a bug .. e.g.

```
void MySWC_Runnabled(void) // [4]
{
    uint8 x = Rte_Read_rInPort_ValueX();  // <- [1]
    uint8 data1 = x / 100; // <- [2]

    Rte_Write_pOutPort_Data1(data1); // <- [3]
    
}
```

1. Input port updates not coming

   - is the input port properly mapped in RTE?
   - has the SWC a DataReadAccess configured for the runnable MySwc_Runnable?
2. integer division always being 0 for values x in range [0..100)
3. Output port updates not coming

   - is the output port properly mapped in RTE?
   - has the SWC a DataWriteAccess configured for the runnable MySwc_Runnable?
4. Is the runnable actually triggered or does it have an unfulfilled activation condition?